# How to show labels outside for multilevel doughnut graph using chart.js

Tags: angular-material, chart.js, angular13

I am able to achieve multilevel doughnut graph as you can see in the image

[image]

but I want the legend and labels for only the outside graph and also how can I set the start and end angle based for the same based on inner graph.

ts file sample code:

```
pieChartPlugins = [];

doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = []      

doughnutChartData: any[] = [
    {
        data: [
           // outer level doughnut data
        ],
        labels: [],
        backgroundColor: []
    },
    {
        data: [
           // inner level doughnut data
        ],
        labels: ['Applied', "Policy Not Applied"],
        backgroundColor: [
            'orange',
            'blue'
        ]
    },
];

doughnutChartOption: any = {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                var index = tooltipItem.index;
                return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
            },
        },
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 50,
            bottom: 50,
        },
    },
    plugins: {
        labels: {
            render: () => { }
        },
        outlabels: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            text: '%v',
            color: 'black',
            stretch: 45,
            padding: 10,
            font: {
                resizable: true,
                minSize: 12,
                maxSize: 14,
            },
        },
    },
    legend: {
        display: false,
        position: 'left',
    },
};
```

html file:

```
<div style="display: block">
                <canvas baseChart [chartType]="doughnutChartType" [datasets]="doughnutChartData" [options]="doughnutChartOption" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
```

chart.js version 2.9.4.

[referred the above code from this link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/)

Comment: working [example](https://codepen.io/BillDou/pen/oNoGBXb)

Comment: @NarenMurali thanks for the quick reply. But can the same be applied with multilevel pie chart?

Comment: am not sure, you need to try yourself, you also have the library [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) One of these should fix your issue